# Updating LinearLayout from other class in Android

Tags: android, class, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I have a class which uses other classes to build up a `FrameLayout`. One is for Navigation through a building, the other for displaying schematics with sensors of it, and the other one to display sensordata. I build up the whole frame one time, and want to make the sensordata visible in the sensorview part of the frame. Lets say I have 5 sensors, and when I click on one the sensorview shows up the sensordata. I could just make 5 sensorviewframes on top of each other, initiating them invisible, and just make the one visible which was selected via a click on a sensor.

I wanted to ask, is it possible to change the `LinearLayout` containing the `TextView`s in a different class with an update method?

I already tried it, but with my code it doesn't work at the moment.

```
public static SensorBar Create_SensorBar_Layout(Context myContext, ObjectStructure objStruct, ObjectView objView, List<SensorDevice> listofCurrentSensordevices)
{   
// Init
    LinearLayout SensorBarLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(myContext);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsSensorBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            200, 653);
    layoutParamsSensorBar.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

    SensorBarLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    SensorBarLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsSensorBar);
    SensorBarLinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.window_frame);
    SensorBarLinearLayout.setPadding(4,4,4,4);  

    LinearLayout SensorBarData = new LinearLayout(myContext);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsSensorBarData = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    SensorBarData.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    SensorBarData.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsSensorBarData);

    //--- Button Headline ---
    Button buttonNavBarHeadline = new Button(myContext);
    buttonNavBarHeadline.setText("Sensordata");
    buttonNavBarHeadline.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonNavBarHeadline.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.mainview_window_headline);
    buttonNavBarHeadline.setTextAppearance(myContext, R.style.headline3);

//Layout buildup
    SensorBarLinearLayout.addView(buttonNavBarHeadline);
    SensorBarLinearLayout.addView(SensorBarData);

    return new SensorBar(SensorBarLinearLayout, SensorBarData);

}
```

This is the Sensorbar, and I want to have the LinearLayout SensorBarData to be dynamically swapped out by clicking on the sensorbuttons.

```
public void updateSensorBar(Context myContext, ObjectStructure objStruct, List<SensorDevice> listofCurrentSensordevices, int activeSensor)
{
LinearLayout linearlayoutSensorvalueTextviews = new LinearLayout(myContext);

... (additional Textviews for Sensordata, which get added with addview())

setSensorBarData(linearlayoutSensorvalueTextviews);
}
```

This is used by an OnClick event.

```
public void setSensorBarData(LinearLayout SensorBarData)    { this.dataSensorBar = SensorBarData; }
```

This is used by the updateSensorBar to update the LinearLayout.

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface and use a callback to let the activity know that a sensor has been updated.

```
public Interface SensorUpdatedListener {
    void onSensorUpdated();
}
```

In your SensorBar class.

```
ArrayList<SensorUpdatedListener > listeners = new ArrayList<SensorUpdatedListener >();

...

public void setSensorUpdatedListener(SensorUpdatedListener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

In your sensor bar update method:

```
for (SensorUpdatedListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onSensorUpdated();
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements SensorUpdatedListener {

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...

    sensorBar.setSensorUpdatedListener(this);
    ...
}

public void onSensorUpdated(){
   // do whatever you need to do
}
```

You could improve the SensorBar class by adding removeSensorUpdatedListener and checking that you do not add the same listener twice in setSensorUpdatedListener.

Comment: Wow, great, I will look into it tomorrow. Thanks for the answer!